# THREE js: Disable auto rotate of sprite

Tags: three.js, rotation, sprite

I used sprites in Three js to display 2d images, the problem that I faced with sprites that they rotate to face the camera.

I am trying to use it to fake a shadow for the 3d object. When I rotate the camera the 3d object tilt with the camera until it makes a 30-degree angle with the horizontal but it's shadow (2d sprite) still at 0 degrees.

How to disable the auto rotation of sprite, or is there another solution to preview 2d images in three js to look like a 3d object?

Answer (score 7):

> How to disable the auto rotation of sprite, or is there another solution to preview 2d images in three js to look like a 3d object?

It's not possible to disable the orientation towards the camera with a flag or configuration. You would have to modify the shader code of `SpriteMaterial` for this.

I suggest you use a mesh instead based on a `PlaneBufferGeometry` and a `MeshBasicMaterial`. Alternatively, you write a custom billboard shader with `ShaderMaterial` or `RawShaderMaterial`.